# My Carousel is going through my header

Tags: php, html

I have created a couple of php documents. When i create the carousel with bootstrap, the carousel goes into the header. Bellow is the code for the index.php and header.php.

Index.php - https://pastebin.com/bAzz3tnZ

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Through The Dimensions - In Development</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #slideshow {
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .carousel-inner {
            max-height: 500px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <?php 
        include_once('header.php');
    ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="slideshow">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="css/images/ttd1.jpg" alt="TTD" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="css/images/ttd2.jpg" alt="TTD" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="css/images/ttd3.jpg" alt="TTD" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
    <?php 
        include_once('footer.php');
    ?>
</body>
```

header.php - https://pastebin.com/0ZtWcG1k

```
<html>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Through The Dimensions</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="members.php">ModPack Testers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><br></li>
          <li><a href="testers/index.php">Testers HQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

P.S - I have edited the padding, but when a use on a mobile device looks at it, its inside it.

Comment: Whats the question? your just describing what the code does

Comment: Im trying to get the the image out of the header so you can see the images on a mobile device. @JasonJoslin

Comment: Here is a image - https://gyazo.com/14c64f3008859638c55cb63c556aa925